# Install4J: How do I restart multiple services after it has been updated in unattended mode without prompting the user for password

Tags: install4j

I use Install4J to install my application which is comprised of two services (two launchers) from a single JAR. I want to update my application in Unattended mode, then stop both services and start both services without having to ask the user to enter the administrator's password. Both services are initially started as root and I have verified using the 'ps' command that they are running as root when one of the services calls the ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication Install4J Integration API method.

My Install4J Updater is able to download the new version and stop the calling launcher, but the problem that I'm seeing is that I'm not able to stop the second (non-calling launcher) nor am I able to start the calling launcher.

This error is very strange because I've noticed that if I stop both services and then start both services using

```
sudo <ServiceLauncher1> stop
sudo <ServiceLauncher2> stop
sudo <ServiceLauncher1> start
sudo <ServiceLauncher2> start
```

..the whole thing works. It downloads the update, stops both services, then starts both services just fine. I've noticed (in OSX) that the launcher icon for the auto updater is also different (black terminal icon (does not work) vs white java icon (works).

I'd very much appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: This is all on Mac OS X? The update installer should stop the services. If it's running as root, I don't see why it should not be able to do that. Can you send the log file of the update installer to support@ej-technologies.com?

Comment: Yes, the problem I've described is on Mac OS X but I'll need a solution that works for both Mac OS X and Windows. Where can I find the log file of the update installer? I see an installation.log in the .install4j directory, but nothing else that looks right.

Comment: The update installer would also copies its log file to .install4j\installation.log if the "Install Files" action is successful. You can pass the arguments `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=[path to log file]` to write the log file to a particular path. You can add these parameters in the action named "Set installer arguments" in the updater installer application in your project.

Comment: There is no Install Files action in the 'Updater with silent version check' application -- only in the 'Installer' application. Is that right? In the 'Set installer arguments' action, I have edited the 'Script' entry to be `return new String[] {"-q", "-wait", "20", "-dir", installationDirectory, "-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true", "-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=<myhomedirectory>/altinstall.log"};` But I get no such log.

Comment: Yes, the updater application downloads the update installer and executes it. The log file will only be created once the downloaded update installer is executed.

Comment: I really think this has to do with permissions. If I run the update installer with `sudo <install_dir>/.install4j/AutoUpdater` everything works fine. Why my service (which is running as root according to `ps`) not able to do the exact same thing as me calling the update installer from my local terminal with `sudo`?

Comment: Maybe it does not go as far as executing the update installer. Is the updater installer application running successfully at all? You can add `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=<myhomedirectory>/altinstall.log` to the "VM parameters" property of the updater application to get the log file of that.

Comment: Thank you @IngoKegel for that tip. I'm finally able to get logging. In the log I'm see that my updater exits after the `Shutdown calling launcher` action. None of the actions that follow this action ever get executed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is the `Run executable or batch file` action that runs afterwards and executes `${installer:updaterDownloadFile}` triggers the `Installer` application which effectively puts all the files in the right places and relaunches the services. Is this right? If so, how can the installer run if the shutdown action kills the updater first?

Comment: OK, I see. Please try to remove the "Shut down calling launcher" action or set its condition expression to `!context.isUnattended()`. For a service launcher that would not be needed, because services are stopped by the installer.

Comment: I'm getting closer. Removing the `Shut down calling launcher` results in the Installer application running which then launches the Uninstaller application which stops the services. The problem I'm seeing now is that when the Uninstaller performs the `Stop a service` for the service that launched the Updater originally, the Uninstaller stops with error code 143 which then stops Installer and ultimately the whole update stops. I have tried performing the action at other places in the Installer and Update, but it seems I can't restart the service that called the Updater or everything stops.

Comment: OK, so this may not be possible. Probably you need another service that is never stopped whose only task is to run the updater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (two services), the Update installer runs as a child process of the service that launched it. Due to part of the update process requiring both services to be stopped and then started the problem is that stopping the calling service causes the whole update installer to be killed.

My solution is to have each service stop/start the other one by using two Update applications in Install4J.

Service #1 --> Updater #1:

1. Check for new version
2. Download new version
3. Install new version
4. Stop Service #2
5. Start Service #2 (At this point, Service #2 is fully updated and running)
6. Notify Service #2 to perform update on Service #1

Service #2 --> Updater #2:

1. Stop Service #1
2. Start Service #1 (At this point, Service #1 is fully updated and running)